# insert statement not inserting records into database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to insert something but it is not working. I haven't programmed in php for a while and am a little rusty. Can someone help ?

Note: the database connection has been made.

new issue

```
 $query= "INSERT INTO products (p_link, detail, price, title, stock, ship_d) VALUES ('$_POST['link']', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1')";
 $results = mysql_query($query, $link);
```

Comment: something wrong with the subject line.

Comment: Have you tried the query in phpMyAdmin ?

Comment: _“I haven't programmed in php for a while”_ – that’s a lame excuse. I you have forgotten how to do proper error checking for MySQL queries via PHP, then go read up on that.

Comment: You need to find out why the query isn't working. 1) Try the query in phpMyAdmin or a database front-end of your choice 2) Copy-paste any error messages you get when running the script here.

Comment: i fixed the last thing but now i am have another problem i get an error when run this. trying to insert a variable. theres a new code there plz help

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the column names should not be wrapped with single quotes , Use backticks instead.

```
 $query= "INSERT INTO products (`p_link`, `detail`, `price`, `title`, `stock`, `ship_d`) VALUES ('1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1')";
```

---

This (`mysql_*`) extension is deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0`, and will be removed in the future. Instead, **Prepared Statements** of [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [`PDO_MySQL`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) extension should be used to ward off SQL Injection attacks !

Comment: actully why not use nothing instead?

Comment: @Dagon Because in PHP `$foo = bar;` is totally a good idea.

Comment: backticks are only necessary when the identifier is a MySQL reserved keyword, or it has spaces.

Comment: @Dagon, What if the OP used a column name as `check` ? Using a backtick is just a fail-safe and no wrong in that.

Comment: @Dagon Quotes are only necessary when the string is a PHP constant, or it has spaces. So...

Answer (score 0):

Adding backticks around column/table names is probably good practice in general - in case one of your columns/tables is a reserved word - but it is not necessary in this case and not the problem with your query. The problem is a mix up with your single quotes in `...('$_POST['link']',...`

Change this:

```
" ... VALUES ('$_POST['link']', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1')";
```

To this:

```
" ... VALUES ('".$_POST['link']."', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1')";
```

Comment: thanks perfect, i apologize i know this stuff but it has been a while since i got back to php form python.

Comment: @user3624411 Great! Glad I could help. Welcome to SO, please make a note that you shouldn't change your question like you did - edits or updates are fine but if the problem is solved please accept the answer that helped you by clicking the checkmark, then create a new question. I was confused by the answer from Shankar Damodaran until I looked at your edit. Future users may run into the same confusion. Thanks and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO products (p_link, detail, price, title, stock, ship_d) VALUES ('".$_POST['link']."', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1')";
```

I think this should work for you.